# How does Tensorflow schedule GPU operations? What is the right GPU scheduling mental model while using TF?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm using Tensorflow's Eager mode to train some neural net models. I'm trying to identify quick wins while optimizing my models for training speed, and my question is about TF's GPU scheduling.

How does Tensorflow decide which operations to schedule on a GPU vs which ones to keep on CPU? Is this a function of operand tensor sizes and operator type? What else?

Is there a way to view which ops were executed on CPU vs GPU? How does it decide to tradeoff the parallelization advantage of GPU vs the time spent shipping data back and forth between GPU and CPU?

Does any of this change for graph mode?

Comment: Please take a look at this document: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/using_gpu

Comment: Thanks @spicyramen. The document describes `log_device_placement` and `config.gpu_options.allow_growth` options as inputs while creating a session, but I'm using eager mode.

Comment: Also, it seems clear from the doc you linked that if `with tf.device()` is used explicitly, then those ops get scheduled on the specified device, but what happens if the user doesn't explicitly specify this?